# How to add a user from another domain to a local domain group?

Tags: c#, active-directory

Using C# I would like to add a user from one domain to a local domain. The domains have a two way trust. Currently I get the error

> 'No principal matching the specified parameters was found.' on the .Save() line.

I have the DN of the user (e.g 'CN=Adams, Sam,OU=Beer, DC=Drinkers,DC=local').

The groups is something like CN=Drunks, OU=Groups,DC=Bars,DC=local.

This works when it is the same domain, but when it is cross domains is when I get the error. The user account that I am using has admin rights locally and read rights in the other domain.

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, m_AD_connection.Domain, m_AD_connection.Path, ContextOptions.Negotiate, m_AD_connection.UserName, m_AD_connection.Password))
{
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, GroupName);
    if (group != null)
    {
        group.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, DN);
        group.Save();
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Any suggestions on what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
group.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, DN);
```

The `context` parameter should be the context required to look up the user, not the group. So you need to create a new `PrincipalContext` for the second domain and pass that to `Add()`. For example:

```
var drinkersPc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "drinkers.local");
group.Members.Add(drinkersPc, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, DN);
```

Comment: That was it.I obviously didn't even consider that. Thanks!